# Animation Nodes - Random Object Data Path Value

Tags: animation-nodes

I need to create several random leafs using Animation Nodes. Each one should be composed of a mesh, an empty, and a Bend/Simple Deformer Modifier to make some deformations. **The mesh and the empty are under a Collection.**

I managed to create a setup using Object Instancer and Collections in order to clone the leaf bend setup.

But I'm having a hard time creating random values for the bend modifier, and I guess this is because the fact that I'm instancing the Collections, therefore, I can't access the Object Data Path because there is no object instanced, but the collection instead. I can't find a way to make the data path of a modifier to be randomly read under an instanced collection.

Does anyone have any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, instances can't have different properties, they share everything except transforms and maybe couple of other things. So what you are asking is not possible.

Comment: Hey @Omar Ahmad, thanks for the input. So not even through loops can't I have the index of the instances to be used as a seed for a angle of a bend object with object data

Comment: No, you would need to copy the object using the *Instancer* node with the *Copy Full Object* option.